# что вставить вместо reply_markup для инлайн клавиатуры

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

суть нажимаешь на инлайн клаву выскакивает текст и ниже должна быть инлайн ссылка как на фото

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='can') 
async def can(call: types.CallbackQuery):
```

Что добавить к коду для инлайн клавиатуры как на фото

Comment: Тебе надо ссылку добавить ? Или наоборот убрать ?

Comment: Добавить к этой кнопке на инлайн клавиатуре

Answer (score 0):

При создании кнопки нужно указать параметр `url`

```
button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти к оплате(Коментарий обязателен)", url="google.com")
```

Подробно о других видах `inline` кнопок и их применении [на YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HCpmxBt_CA&t=620s).